# Django / Python, calling a specific class / function on every user Request

Tags: python, django, request

I was looking over the Django documentation on a way to do this but didn't see anything, though I may have missed it as I'm not sure exactly where to look... I want to be able to perform a specific action on every user request, such as instantiating a class and calling one of its functions, however the only way I know of to do this now is to put it in each view function. Is there a better way to do this, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use Django's [middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) functionality.